# Text File delimiting - Performance issue

Tags: c#

I have a text file with details as follows with no headers

```
 Name1 Text1 This is the message1
 Name2 Text2 This is the message2
```

If I use like this..

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile.log");
for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++
{
    string[] items = allLines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' });
    MessageBox.Show("This is Name field : " + items[0])      
    MessageBox.Show("This is Text field : " + items[1])      
    MessageBox.Show("This is Message field : " + items[2])      
}
```

If I use the above code, it will work fine for first 2 fields but how can I get the third column "This is the message1" in single column?

Comment: One more question. Consider now Name field is a Date field. If Name field contains date with format as follows [10-10-2013 10.10.10.333 CDF]. How can I get the first column with whole data with brackets into first column with Split of space ' '. Here it tries to break after reading the only date of Name column. Could you please suggest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just specify that you want at most 3 items when splitting using the appropriate overload of the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) method:

```
string[] items = allLines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 3);
```

Comment: Here how can I read the last column into a single column "This is the message1"

Comment: What table are you talking about?

Comment: I have resolved it. Thanks a lot. But one more question. Here the space between the columns in the text file can have more than one space. How can I solve it? Will Split work here?

Comment: @CPK_2011 You can use `string[] items = fco.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Salute to you Sirs. You have simplified my coding. I am grateful to you. Thanks a lot.